# How to dynamically generate html headers from .csv using first record along with css style

Tags: html, awk

I have a Scenario  where I am printing the Headers

But I am passing manually the header name in the awk code

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { print "<HTML><TABLE border=\"1\"><TR bgcolor=\"black\"><TH><font color=\"#FFFFFF\"> NAME </font> </TH><TH><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">COURSE</font></TH></TR>" 
}
{
    printf "<TR>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
    print "</TR>"
}
END { print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>" }' /d/file.csv > /d/file.html
```

Sample file .csv

```
NAME,CITY,COURSE
A,B,AA
B,A,BB   
M,MA,MD 
RAM,SU,GM  
VIK,HU,JI
```

The .csv file will contain the first record as Headers 
how many fields are their in first record that's how the headers should be created dynamically with style **bg_color=black** and **font-color=white**

The purpose of dynamic header is that it will reduce the manual way writing of Headers each time ... reusability will be their ...

Comment: is there a reason you didn't choose a higher level language ? Here is an example using `javascript`: http://bl.ocks.org/ndarville/7075823

Comment: @azbarcea Yes I need it in Linux way only. I am not able to buld up logic to dynamically create header using .csv first record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following once.

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN{
  print "<HTML>\
         <TABLE border=\"1\">"
}
FNR==1{
  print "<TR bgcolor=\"black\">"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     printf "<TH style=\"color:white\">%s</TH>%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
  }
  print "</TR>"
  next
}
{
    printf "<TR>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
    print "</TR>"
}
END{
    print "</TABLE>"ORS"</BODY>" ORS "</HTML>"
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - wonderful as expected Thanks man. Will you be able to identify way of attaching file to sendmail for this same problem approach

Comment: @hitrurorda, your Welcome. Request you to please keep 1 question 1 thread, you can search forums if you don't find anything open a new thread then, cheers.